# Convert to hexadecimal with multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, radix

So Im writing a code for base 16 to base 10 conversion without int or hex. Im not sure how to make it work for multiple hex values. So sample input is something like: 48, 42, 6D, 62, 59, 61, and it should come out as: HBmbYa. This is the code:

```
def __getdecdigit(digit):
    digits = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
              'A','B','C','D','E','F'']
    for x in range (len(digits)):
        if digit == digits[x]:
            return x
        
def hextodec (hexnum):
    decNum=0
    power = 0
    for digits in range (len(hexnum), 0, -1):
        decNum = decNum + 16 ** power * __getdecdigit(hexnum[digits-1])
        power+=1
    return decNum
    
hexnum = input("What is ur string? ")
hexnum = hexnum.upper()
decNum = hextodec(hexnum)
asciii = chr(decNum)
print(asciii)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
def __getdecdigit(digit):
    digits = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
              'A','B','C','D','E','F']
    for x in range (len(digits)):
        if digit == digits[x]:
            return x
        
def hextodec (hexnum):
    decNum=0
    power = 0
    for digits in range (len(hexnum), 0, -1):
        decNum = decNum + 16 ** power * __getdecdigit(hexnum[digits-1])
        power+=1
    return decNum
    
hexnum = input("What is ur string? ") # 48, 42, 6D, 62, 59, 61
hexnum = hexnum.upper()
hexls=hexnum.split(',')
res=[]
for val in hexls: # just wrap it with loop
     result=hextodec(val.strip())
     res.append(chr(result))
print(''.join(res))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> What is ur string? 48, 42, 6D, 62, 59, 61
>>> HBmbYa
```